# Не выводится открытие и закрытие html формы

Tags: html, form

Вот что в коде:

```
<div class="form-block">
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <!--<form action="" method="POST">-->
        <div class="line-block">
            <label for="name">Имя</label>
            <input class="text" id="name" name="name" type="text" value=""/>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="line-block">
            <label for="mail">E-mail</label>
            <input class="text" id="mail" name="email" type="text" value=""/>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="line-block">
            <label for="question">Вопрос</label>
            <textarea cols="0" id="question" name="Message" onfocus="this.value=''; this.onfocus=null;" rows="0"></textarea>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="line-block">
            <font color="yellow">
                <span id="err3"></span>
            </font>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-button">
            <input class="bigest-blue-button" name="send_submit" type="submit" value="Отправить"/>
        </div>
        <!--</form>-->
    </form>
</div>
```

При выводе почему-то пропадают теги `<form></form>`. Там где они должны быть, скопировал их и закомментировал. Из-за чего это происходит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут вы не закрыли тег form - 
<form action="" method="POST" name="second" onsubmit="return validate2()"/>

соответственно тег вы не видете в firebug или где вы там дебагером смотрите

Comment: тег формы закрывается не так в том доктайпе что указан, и это никак не влияет

Comment: да, дело было в не закрытом теге предыдущей формы. Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 2):

А что ещё за слэш в конце?

```
<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate3()"/>
```

И ничего никуда не пропадает (скрин):

[image]

Comment: убрал его, как то случайно он туда забрел:) Но изменений нет - форма не работает(

Comment: validate3()  - проверка формы. Да, в исходном коде в Опере смотрю - есть открытие и закрытие формы, через "происпектировать элемент" - нет. И при нажатии на кнопку форма не работает

Comment: Дык, дело явно в JS. Если отменяеся обычное действие для события **submit** на время проверки, то надо ж где-то его и запустить, если проверка пройдена ))

Comment: убрал эту проверку, но форма не активна остается

Comment: Хорошо, а как вы добавляете форму на страницу? Она прописана изначально или инклюдится, или с помощью JS?

Comment: прописана изначально

Answer (score 0):

1. С формы можно убрать комментарии, что бы она работала.
2. Если Вы выбираете элемент по имени или по тегу, это всегда подразумевается, набор элементов, тобишь массив, и то, что сейчас у Вас `var name = document.getElementsByName('name').value;`
   Должно выглядеть так: `var name = document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value;`
3. Я бы переделал логику отправки формы, не возвращал саму форму в онсабмит, а сделал проще и прозрачней. Вернул бы сразу фолс, и передал при онсабмит эту форму как аргумент, и когда прошло все валидацию отпарвил бы ее.

   ```
   <form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="validate3(this); return false;">

   function validate3(from)
   ```

Comment: > 1 - С формы можно убрать коментарии, что бы она работала.

Это какое-то новое правило, которое я проспал? ))

Comment: На форме не рабтает клик потому что сам тег формы закоментирован, на сайте по крайней мере так. На который вы дали линк

Comment: дело не в JS, я эту проверку вообще сейчас убрал. Проблема в неработающей кнопке из-за отсутствия тегов открытия и закрытия формы

Comment: Как вы хотите получить работающую форму, когда тегов форм нету??

Comment: в этом и была проблема, но уже найден баг